# Chrome extension (manifest 3): Keep popup open

Tags: google-chrome-extension, plugins

I'm develop Google Chrome extension, when i try to load a file to my extension, during the search for it in folder popup apparently lose focus and close. what I need is keeping the popup open during this process of select a file. how can I do that, working around the problem present in manifest 3.

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome. You'll have to open the popup in a new window by using chrome.windows.create.